# How do I retrieve a column of data as an array using vba - from an SSMS database

Tags: excel, vba, ssms

I am looking to return a a column of data to be used as a combo box within excel. To do this I am using a recordset to return my data from a stored procedure. The problem I am having is that I can't figure out how to populate or even display the information I am returning - or even if I am returning all the data.

I know there are solutions online that recommend using "rs.GetRows" to populate an array, however I have had no luck with this. I had originally intended to populate an array by indexing through the records in the recordset and adding them individually. The problem with this is I can never get the size of the recordset and because I am using dynamic SQL the size of my array is never the same. I have been at this for a while and I was wondering if there is a good way to do this.

**VBA Code**

```
Public Sub SQL_SP_Column_Data2(ByVal sql_col As String, _
                               ByVal sql_table As String)

    On Error GoTo RunTimeError

    Dim array1() As Variant

    Dim sqlconxn As ADODB.connection
    Dim sqlcmd As ADODB.Command ' Operates as a command between SQL and vba
    Dim sqlrs As ADODB.recordSet

    Dim conxnString As String 

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' String used to establish a connection to the database
    conxnString = "driver={SQL Server};" & _
                  "server='server_name';" & _
                  "uid='username';" & _
                  "pwd='password';" & _
                  "database='database_name';"

    Set sqlconxn = New ADODB.connection
    Set sqlcmd = New ADODB.Command
    Set sqlrs = New ADODB.recordSet

    sqlconxn.ConnectionTimeout = 30
    sqlconxn.Open conxnString ' makes the connection between SQL

    MsgBox "Connection 1 state: " & GetState2(sqlconxn.state) 

    sqlcmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc ' sets command to a stored procedure
    sqlcmd.CommandText = "GET_COLUMN_DATA" ' name of the stored procedure
    sqlcmd.ActiveConnection = sqlconxn ' makes the sql connection

    sqlcmd.Parameters.Append _
        sqlcmd.CreateParameter("@column_name", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, sql_col)
    sqlcmd.Parameters.Append _
        sqlcmd.CreateParameter("@data_table_name", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, sql_table)

    sqlrs.Open sqlcmd

    If sqlrs.EOF Then

        array1() = sqlrs.GetRows
        Debug.Print "VALUES: " + array1(i)
        sqlrs.MoveNext
        i = i + 1

    End If

RunTimeError:     ' Reportd any errors that might occur in the system and

    Dim strError As String
    strError = "ERROR: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description
    MsgBox strError
    Debug.Print strError

Exit Sub

End Sub
```

I am using GetRows above because it was the most recommended method, but I can't get it to work the way I am intending it to. In this example I usually get ERROR: 0 or subscript out of range.

**SQL Stored Procedure**

```
USE AFCD
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GET_COLUMN_DATA (@column_name nvarchar(max),
                     @data_table_name nvarchar(max)) AS

BEGIN

    DECLARE @query nvarchar(max)

    SET @query = 'SELECT ' + @column_name + 
             ' FROM ' + @data_table_name + ''

    EXEC sp_executesql @query

END
```

When I test this stored procedure I actually get the data that I want to I know my stored procedure is returning what I want, but I don't know how to get that within vba.

Example of expected outputs: 
If the inputs into the the vba sub are - "WIRE_TYPE", "WIRE_INDEX"

```
SQL_SP_Column_Data2 "WIRE_TYPE", "WIRE_INDEX"
```

Then the output should look like this:

```
Stainless Steel
Steel ER70S-3
Steel ER70S-6
Titanium(1)
Titanium(2)
```

**SOLUTION** - This part of code refers to my vba and is right after I execute my SQL SP. Credit to Tim Williams for the answer.

```
 If Not sqlrs.EOF Then

        array1() = sqlrs.GetRows()

    End If

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To 4

        Debug.Print "VALUES: " + array1(0, i) ' 2D array!!!

    Next i
```

Comment: ` If Not sqlrs.EOF Then` and `GetRows` fetches all rows, so you don't call it in a loop using `Movenext`

Comment: I removed the if statement and sqlrs.movenext and just used sqlrs.GetRows instead. That line of code actually compiled as I was debugging it but when I tried printing any of the values in the array I got the error:  "Subscript out of range"

Comment: Can you edit your question to add how you're trying to print the values?  Remember GetRows() returns a 2-D array, so you need to provide both dimensions  - eg. `array1(1, 2)`

Comment: Ha! that's why my subscript was out of range, I honestly didn't know GetRows() returned a 2-D array. My array has only a single column so I didn't think it applied. Thank you very much, you solved my problem. Now I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `If` test is off, and GetRows doesn't need a loop:

```
If Not sqlrs.EOF Then
    array1() = sqlrs.GetRows()
End If
```

Remember `GetRows()` returns a zero-based 2-D array, so you need to provide both dimensions when accessing values eg.

```
array1(0, 2)  'first field, third row
```